# Callback Validator not firing?

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

Whenever I submit the form I'm expecting for `die()` to get fired the Callback Validator doesn't seem to get triggered?

I can't figure out what else I'm missing as I just based this on several examples I saw online.

```
$inputFilter->add([
                'name' => 'flag_reference',
                'required' => true,
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'filters' => [
                    ['name' => StripTags::class],
                    ['name' => StringTrim::class]
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name' => Callback::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'messages' => [
                                Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Not a valid Reference'
                            ],
                            'callback' => function($value, $context) {
                                die('here');
                                $flagReference= $value;
                                var_dump('flag reference', $value);
                                $flag = $context['flag'];
                                var_dump('flag', $canonicalFlag);exit;
                                $isValid = false;
                                if($flag== 'checked') {
                                    $isValid = $flagReference ? true : false;
                                }

                                return $isValid;
                            }
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
```

I'm expecting the response to be 'here' but I just get validation errors for the other elements.

Basically I'm trying to accomplish a conditional `required`.

If a checkbox is checked (`flag`), the value for a textbox must not be empty (`flag_reference`).

Comment: Have you tried to set the `continue_if_empty` option? Validators are not fired automatically, when an element is allowed to be empty. Just set `'continue_if_empty' => true` and try again. Does that help?

Comment: Are you using the correct Callback class? (in Validator namespace instead of Filter)

Comment: @Marcel I will try that later and will let you know if it will work.

Comment: @rkeet Yes, I am using the one from the Validator namespace

Comment: Is the InputFilter added on to the Form? Depending on your setup you might have to do this manually due to SoC. Also, are the other Validators (also from other fields in the form) getting fired?

Comment: @rkeet What specifically do you mean by "added on to the Form"? I'm not really attaching the filter to any Forms, I'm using the Filter as a standalone. I invoke `$filter->setData($data)` to feed it the data that need to be filtered.

Comment: You could use separate InputFilter class and/or Fieldset class and add those to the form. Seeing the first sentence ("Whenever I submit the form I'm...") that was an option. If you're invoking this one specifically, then it's weird indeed. Could you add `'break_chain_on_failure' => true,` as an option to see if that helps? (Adds a 'stop propagation' thingy if it encounters an error instead of saving errors till all filters/validators have run)

Comment: @rkeet That's a neat suggestion, haven't come across that one yet, will try that too. Thank you